# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for dummy Firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm learning to set up Firebase Emulators correctly to work on my projects and I came up with a problem. I can setup the emulators and make them work locally, however, when trying to access firestore it seems to try to access the real Firestore Instance instead of the emulator.

Right now I'm initializing the app like this (in Cloud Functions)

```js
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
```

But when I'm running a function I'm getting:

> Failed to initialize and load triggers. This shouldn't happen: Failed to read credentials from file GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.json'

The thing is that if I use the credentials I generated for my project it will work with the real Firestore instance instead of the emulator.

How should I make credentials for my emulated services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Firebase Functions emulator as well then Admin SDK will connect to all the running emulators e.g. if only Auth emulator is running then it'll use the emulator and connect to production for other services like Firestore. You can explicitly set the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable and Admin SDKs will use the emulator then.

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#admin_sdks) for more information.

Comment: Just tried this and didn't work. It stills asks me for the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

Comment: Oh I think we got it. I set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST and it didn't work, but I thought it could be because I already had setup GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS set. So I unset it and left only FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST. Now is working as expected.

It is important to note that if I want to have everything working with the emulators, GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS shouldn't be set. Is that correct?